# converting one form of json into another form of json object using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, if-statement, nodes

here `data1` and order of `content` get changed everytime that why I used switch statement
I am running a function by passing value like this

```
parser(values[key]);
```

this value[key]) contain bellow object
The following object / data-structure

```
  {
    "nodeType": "document",
    "data": {},
    "content": [
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "dummy testing bold",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "bold"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "jsdbhcjbjsdz'c;s bold and italic",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "bold"
              },
              {
                "type": "italic"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "underline bold and italic",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "bold"
              },
              {
                "type": "italic"
              },
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "ldwc;s,l;,aws italic",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "italic"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "hr",
        "content": [],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "testing",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "italic"
              },
              {
                "type": "code"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "unordered-list",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "list-item",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [
                  {
                    "nodeType": "text",
                    "value": "hello ji",
                    "marks": [
                      {
                        "type": "italic"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "code"
                      }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "list-item",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [
                  {
                    "nodeType": "text",
                    "value": "nahi ji",
                    "marks": [
                      {
                        "type": "italic"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "code"
                      }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "list-item",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [
                  {
                    "nodeType": "text",
                    "value": "testing ji",
                    "marks": [
                      {
                        "type": "underline"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "italic"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "bold"
                      }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "ordered-list",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "list-item",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [
                  {
                    "nodeType": "text",
                    "value": "testing",
                    "marks": [
                      {
                        "type": "italic"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "code"
                      }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "list-item",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [
                  {
                    "nodeType": "text",
                    "value": "newh",
                    "marks": [
                      {
                        "type": "italic"
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "code"
                      }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "blockquote",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "blockquotes",
                "marks": [
                  {
                    "type": "italic"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "code"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "blockquotes",
                "marks": [
                  {
                    "type": "bold"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "code"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "underline"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "heading-1",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "Heading 1",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "bold"
              },
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "heading-2",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 2",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "italic"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "heading-3",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 3",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "italic"
              },
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "heading-4",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 4",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "bold"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "heading-5",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 5",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "heading-6",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 6",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "italic"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "hr",
        "content": [],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "embedded-entry-block",
        "content": [],
        "data": {
          "target": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "651dYO8d4oE0MVJlVePWr6",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Entry"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "hyperlink",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "Google",
                "marks": [],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "uri": "www.google.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "entry-hyperlink",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "Entry",
                "marks": [],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "target": {
                "sys": {
                  "id": "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
                  "type": "Link",
                  "linkType": "Entry"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "asset-hyperlink",
            "content": [
              {
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "Asset",
                "marks": [],
                "data": {}
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "target": {
                "sys": {
                  "id": "2FfbMwKRZ2QK52MsbYxZbb",
                  "type": "Link",
                  "linkType": "Asset"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "hi code here",
            "marks": [
              {
                "type": "code"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "embedded-entry-block",
        "content": [],
        "data": {
          "target": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "4zu7f2YP4cXqR6aeeMxEt8",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Entry"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "embedded-entry-inline",
            "content": [],
            "data": {
              "target": {
                "sys": {
                  "id": "4zu7f2YP4cXqR6aeeMxEt8",
                  "type": "Link",
                  "linkType": "Entry"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "embedded-entry-block",
        "content": [],
        "data": {
          "target": {
            "sys": {
              "id": "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
              "type": "Link",
              "linkType": "Entry"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nodeType": "paragraph",
        "content": [
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "embedded-entry-inline",
            "content": [],
            "data": {
              "target": {
                "sys": {
                  "id": "49VJ3thpTULacWCcnjbOXz",
                  "type": "Link",
                  "linkType": "Entry"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }
        ],
        "data": {}
      }
    ]
  }
```

... should be converted into another custom structure like the following one ...

```
 [
    {
      "type": "doc",
      "attrs": { "dirty": true },
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "dummy testing bold", "bold": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [
            {
              "text": "jsdbhcjbjsdz'c;s bold and italic",
              "bold": true,
              "italic": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [
            {
              "text": "underline bold and italic",
              "bold": true,
              "italic": true,
              "underline": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "idwc:s,l:.aws italic", "italic": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "italic": true, "text": "" }]
        },
        {
          "type": "hr",
          "children": [{ "text": "" }],
          "attrs": { "dirty": true }
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "" }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "testing", "italic": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "ul",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "li",
              "attrs": { "dirty": true },
              "children": [{ "italic": true, "text": "hello ji" }]
            },
            {
              "type": "li",
              "attrs": { "dirty": true },
              "children": [{ "italic": true, "text": "nahi ji" }]
            },
            {
              "type": "li",
              "attrs": { "dirty": true },
              "children": [
                {
                  "text": "testing ji",
                  "italic": true,
                  "bold": true,
                  "underline": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "id": "6c180306f6204829999b78e8dd482d33",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true }
        },
        {
          "type": "ol",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "li",
              "children": [{ "text": "testing", "italic": true }],
              "attrs": { "dirty": true }
            },
            {
              "type": "li",
              "attrs": { "dirty": true },
              "children": [{ "italic": true, "text": "newh" }]
            }
          ],
          "id": "10207a886ca241419b66a3b155bac028",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true }
        },
        {
          "type": "blockquote",
          "children": [
            { "text": "blockquotes\n\n", "italic": true, "underline": true },
            { "text": "blockquotes", "underline": true, "bold": true }
          ],
          "attrs": { "dirty": true }
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "" }]
        },
        {
          "type": "h1",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "Heading 1", "bold": true, "underline": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "h2",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "heading 2", "italic": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "h3",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [
            { "text": "heading 3", "italic": true, "underline": true }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "h4",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "heading 4", "bold": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "h5",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "heading 5", "underline": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "h6",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "heading 6", "italic": true }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "italic": true, "text": "" }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "italic": true, "text": "" }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [
            { "italic": true, "text": "" },
            {
              "type": "a",
              "attrs": {
                "url": "www.google.com",
                "target": "_self",
                "dirty": true
              },
              "children": [{ "text": "Google" }]
            },
            { "text": "" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "" }]
        },        
        {
          "type": "code",
          "attrs": { "language": "html", "dirty": true },
          "children": [{ "text": "hi code here" }]
        },
        {
          "type": "p",
          "attrs": { "dirty": true },
          "children": [
            { "text": "" },
            {
              "type": "reference",
              "attrs": {
                "display-type": "inline",
                "type": "entry",
                "class-name": "embedded-entry redactor-component inline-entry",
                "entry-uid": "bltccc6338d24478e6f",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "content-type-uid": "rte",
                "dirty": true
              },
              "children": [{ "text": "" }]
            },
            { "text": "" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

```
  {
            "nodeType": "document",
            "data": {},
            "content": [
                {
                    "nodeType": "ordered-list",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "nodeType": "list-item",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "nodeType": "paragraph",
                                    "content": [
                                        {
                                            "nodeType": "text",
                                            "value": "order list value 1",
                                            "marks": [],
                                            "data": {}
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "data": {}
                                }
                            ],
                            "data": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "nodeType": "list-item",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "nodeType": "paragraph",
                                    "content": [
                                        {
                                            "nodeType": "text",
                                            "value": "order list value 2 with bold and italic",
                                            "marks": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "bold"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "type": "italic"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "data": {}
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "data": {}
                                }
                            ],
                            "data": {}
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                },
                {
                    "nodeType": "heading-3",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "nodeType": "text",
                            "value": "with Heading 3 value",
                            "marks": [],
                            "data": {}
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                },
                {
                    "nodeType": "paragraph",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "nodeType": "text",
                            "value": "hi normal text",
                            "marks": [],
                            "data": {}
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                },
                {
                    "nodeType": "paragraph",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "nodeType": "text",
                            "value": "bold text here",
                            "marks": [
                                {
                                    "type": "bold"
                                }
                            ],
                            "data": {}
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                },
                {
                    "nodeType": "paragraph",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "nodeType": "text",
                            "value": "bold and italic same data test",
                            "marks": [
                                {
                                    "type": "bold"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "italic"
                                }
                            ],
                            "data": {}
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {}
                }
            ]
        },
```

I already came up with a switch statement in order to check the incoming data and store it in the same format or place which I am getting from the first object

Mapper.js

```
const {
  bold,
  italic,
  underline,
  h1,
  h2,
} = require("./Schema");

module.exports = jsonRTEMapper = (data) => {
  const jsonSchema = [];
  for (const nodeType of data) {
    if (
      nodeType.content.length !== undefined &&
      nodeType.content.length !== 0
    ) {
      switch (nodeType.nodeType) {
        case "paragraph":
          for (const mark of nodeType.content) {
            if (
              mark.marks !== undefined &&
              mark.marks.length !== undefined &&
              mark.marks.length !== 0
            ) {
              for (const type of mark.marks) {
                switch (type.type) {
                  case "bold":
                    jsonSchema.push(bold(nodeType.content));
                    break;
                  case "italic":
                    jsonSchema.push(italic(nodeType.content));
                    break;
                  case "underline":
                    jsonSchema.push(underline(nodeType.content));
                    break;
                  case "code":
                    jsonSchema.push(code(nodeType.content));
                    break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          break;
        case "heading-1":
          jsonSchema.push(h1(nodeType.content));
          break;
        case "heading-2":
          jsonSchema.push(h2(nodeType.content));
          break;     
      }
    }
  }
};
```

and in jsonSchema I am pushing the return data which I got from the function which I wrote in different file

Schema.js

```
function bold(data) {
  for (const value of data) {
    return {
      type: "p",
      attrs: { dirty: true },
      children: [{ text: value.value, bold: true }],
    };
  }
}
function italic(data) {
  for (const value of data) {
    return {
      type: "p",
      attrs: { dirty: true },
      children: [{ text: value.value, italic: true }],
    };
  }
}
function h1(data) {
  for (const value of data) {
    return {
      type: "h1",
      attrs: { dirty: true },
      children: [{ text: value.value }],
    };
  }
}
function h2(data) {
  for (const value of data) {
    return {
      type: "h2",
      attrs: { dirty: true },
      children: [{ text: value.value }],
    };
  }
}
```

the problem is it is working perfectly fine when the type is single for eg if type is boat or internal or underline it work fine but when the type contain more then one type then how to use make the expected output that is not possible by me

as I am looking of the solution if any object contain type:"bold" type:italic it should replace with the bold:true italic:true or underline or inside type:code

just wanted to replace this type and fetch the json object as expected json object but don't know how to do it

Comment: you can try doing some console logs in the middle to see if data getting properly

Comment: if you are not returning anything from `.map` you should probably be using `.forEach`

Comment: also, how is `arraySchema` coming out as null? I don't see anywhere where you are setting it to null. If none of the conditional hit you would think it would come out to `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. The deeply nested nature of this code makes it hard to read however

Comment: Another thing, the first `writeFile` method shouldn't be working. [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) expects three arguments and you only have two. This should be throwing an `ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK` TypeError. Have you run this code successfully?

Comment: Why does your expected result have two blocks of code? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all the mappers/parsers in a map you won't have to use switch case statements. And things will be easier to implement:

```js
// parsers.js ------------------------------    
// put all parsing logic in this file

const parsers = new Map();

// once all the parsers are implemented you don't need this check
parsers._get = parsers.get;
parsers.get = function(key) {
  if (this.has(key))
    return this._get(key);
  return () => console.warn(`Parser not implemented for: ${JSON.stringify(key)}`);
}

// map all the parsers 
// keys should be exactly same as keys in input json
parsers.set('document', parseDocument);
parsers.set('paragraph', parseParagraph);
parsers.set('text', parseText);
parsers.set('hr', parseHR);
parsers.set('list-item', parseLI);
parsers.set('unordered-list', parseUL);
parsers.set('ordered-list', parseOL);

// TODO: implement remaining 15 element types
//parsers.set('', parse);

function convert(obj) {
  return [parsers.get(obj.nodeType)(obj)];
};


function parseDocument(obj) {
  let type = 'doc';
  let attrs = { "dirty": true }
  let children = [];

  obj.content.forEach(e => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));

  return { type, children, attrs };
}

function parseParagraph(obj) {
  let type = 'p';
  let attrs = { "dirty": true }
  let children = [];

  obj.content.forEach(e => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  return { type, children, attrs };
}

function parseText(obj) {
  const result = {};
  result.text = obj.value;
  obj.marks.forEach(e => result[e.type] = true);
  return result;
}

function parseHR(obj) {
  let type = 'hr';
  let attrs = { "dirty": true }
  let children = [];
  return { type,  attrs, children };
}

function parseUL(obj) {
  let type = 'ul';
  let attrs = { "dirty": true }
  let children = [];

  obj.content.forEach(e => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  return { type, children, attrs };
}

function parseOL(obj) {
  let type = 'ol';
  let attrs = { "dirty": true }
  let children = [];

  obj.content.forEach(e => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  return { type, children, attrs };
}

function parseLI(obj) {
  let type = 'li';
  let attrs = { "dirty": true }
  let children = [];

  obj.content.forEach(e => children.push(parsers.get(e.nodeType)(e)));
  // get rid of paragraph elements
  children = children.map(c => c.children).flat();

  return { type, children, attrs };
}

// mapper.js ---------------------------------------------
let result = convert(getSrcData());
console.log('Converted object: ', result);

let result2 = convert(getSrcData2());
console.log('Converted object2: ', result2);

function getSrcData() {
  return {
      "nodeType": "document",
      "data": {},
      "content": [{
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "dummy testing bold",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "bold"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "jsdbhcjbjsdz'c;s bold and italic",
            "marks": [{
                "type": "bold"
              },
              {
                "type": "italic"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "underline bold and italic",
            "marks": [{
                "type": "bold"
              },
              {
                "type": "italic"
              },
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "ldwc;s,l;,aws italic",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "italic"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "hr",
          "content": [],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "testing",
            "marks": [{
                "type": "italic"
              },
              {
                "type": "code"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "unordered-list",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "list-item",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [{
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "hello ji",
                  "marks": [{
                      "type": "italic"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "code"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "list-item",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [{
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "nahi ji",
                  "marks": [{
                      "type": "italic"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "code"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "list-item",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [{
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "testing ji",
                  "marks": [{
                      "type": "underline"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "italic"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "bold"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "ordered-list",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "list-item",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [{
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "testing",
                  "marks": [{
                      "type": "italic"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "code"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "list-item",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "paragraph",
                "content": [{
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "newh",
                  "marks": [{
                      "type": "italic"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "code"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "blockquote",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "blockquotes",
                "marks": [{
                    "type": "italic"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "code"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "blockquotes",
                "marks": [{
                    "type": "bold"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "code"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "underline"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "heading-1",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "Heading 1",
            "marks": [{
                "type": "bold"
              },
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "heading-2",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 2",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "italic"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "heading-3",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 3",
            "marks": [{
                "type": "italic"
              },
              {
                "type": "underline"
              }
            ],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "heading-4",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 4",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "bold"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "heading-5",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 5",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "underline"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "heading-6",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "heading 6",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "italic"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "hr",
          "content": [],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "embedded-entry-block",
          "content": [],
          "data": {
            "target": {
              "sys": {
                "id": "651dYO8d4oE0MVJlVePWr6",
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Entry"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "hyperlink",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "Google",
                "marks": [],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {
                "uri": "www.google.com"
              }
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "entry-hyperlink",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "Entry",
                "marks": [],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {
                "target": {
                  "sys": {
                    "id": "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
                    "type": "Link",
                    "linkType": "Entry"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "asset-hyperlink",
              "content": [{
                "nodeType": "text",
                "value": "Asset",
                "marks": [],
                "data": {}
              }],
              "data": {
                "target": {
                  "sys": {
                    "id": "2FfbMwKRZ2QK52MsbYxZbb",
                    "type": "Link",
                    "linkType": "Asset"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "hi code here",
            "marks": [{
              "type": "code"
            }],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "embedded-entry-block",
          "content": [],
          "data": {
            "target": {
              "sys": {
                "id": "4zu7f2YP4cXqR6aeeMxEt8",
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Entry"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
            "nodeType": "text",
            "value": "",
            "marks": [],
            "data": {}
          }],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "embedded-entry-inline",
              "content": [],
              "data": {
                "target": {
                  "sys": {
                    "id": "4zu7f2YP4cXqR6aeeMxEt8",
                    "type": "Link",
                    "linkType": "Entry"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "embedded-entry-block",
          "content": [],
          "data": {
            "target": {
              "sys": {
                "id": "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Entry"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nodeType": "paragraph",
          "content": [{
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "embedded-entry-inline",
              "content": [],
              "data": {
                "target": {
                  "sys": {
                    "id": "49VJ3thpTULacWCcnjbOXz",
                    "type": "Link",
                    "linkType": "Entry"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "text",
              "value": "",
              "marks": [],
              "data": {}
            }
          ],
          "data": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }


    function getSrcData2() {
      return  {
          "nodeType": "document",
          "data": {},
          "content": [
            {
              "nodeType": "ordered-list",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "list-item",
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "nodeType": "paragraph",
                      "content": [
                        {
                          "nodeType": "text",
                          "value": "order list value 1",
                          "marks": [],
                          "data": {}
                        }
                      ],
                      "data": {}
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                },
                {
                  "nodeType": "list-item",
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "nodeType": "paragraph",
                      "content": [
                        {
                          "nodeType": "text",
                          "value": "order list value 2 with bold and italic",
                          "marks": [
                            {
                              "type": "bold"
                            },
                            {
                              "type": "italic"
                            }
                          ],
                          "data": {}
                        }
                      ],
                      "data": {}
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "heading-3",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "with Heading 3 value",
                  "marks": [],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "hi normal text",
                  "marks": [],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "bold text here",
                  "marks": [
                    {
                      "type": "bold"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            },
            {
              "nodeType": "paragraph",
              "content": [
                {
                  "nodeType": "text",
                  "value": "bold and italic same data test",
                  "marks": [
                    {
                      "type": "bold"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "italic"
                    }
                  ],
                  "data": {}
                }
              ],
              "data": {}
            }
          ]
        };
    }
```

```html
<b>See console logs for the output.</b>
```

Explanation is in code comments. I've laid down the framework and implemented parsers for 6 element types. Rest you can implement easily. While implementing remaining types you'll understand the code very well.

- Use Developer tool's [code debugging features](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript) to understand the code. Or use VSCode to [debug nodejs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) code.
- Use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu to analyze input and output JSONs.

Comment: Hi @the Hutt i have few doubt like here 1. `parsers.set('richTextEditor', parseDocument);` here the name `richTextEditor` is user added name so everytime it get changed so I don't want to add manually it can be anything.
2. I made parser.js file and wrote above code till //mapper.js and and I am I called it by let result = parse(data); its not working its showing me `Parser not implemented for: "nodeType"
Parser not implemented for: "data"
Parser not implemented for: "content"`

Comment: @Vikas 1. if the root node(`richTextEditor`) has fixed format then don't register it in the map just call the parser by hard coding it. 2. why your code is passing 'nodeType' string to the `parsers.get` method? it is should be value inside `obj.nodeType`. You really need to debug your code using some IDE like VSCode.

Comment: `richTextEditor` is the name of the object and its not have fixed format that why i used switch statement to check `paragrabh h1 h2` who ever come first can be assign in there respective order in this example you can see bold and italic came first but what if the h1 came first or order list came first

Comment: Hi @the hutt you can see I have updated the question here testing is another object name and it contain different format as its upon user what he want that's why I used switch statement

Comment: @Vikas I've done small change now the code works with both the inputs. In the demo I've parsed both the inputs.

Comment: Hi @the hutt Sorry I mistakenly added some key in the output that is `richTextEditor` and the `testing` while doing console.log() I got to know that I am calling the function by passing the value not with key can you help me last time by removing the `richTextEditor` and `testing` and just by passing the value please

Comment: I have updated my question you will get clear understanding what I am trying to achieve or what data I am trying to pass in parser() function

Comment: That makes it easy. See the updated code.

Comment: can we remove that parser not implemented for warning ?

Comment: If you implement parser functions for remaining elements then the warning will automatically go away. :)  Code for other 19 elements is almost same, so I left it for you.

Comment: Hi @theHutt I tried your solution in oneof my project and I am stuck at this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/72008082/18628258 as in parserBlock I want multiple output but it is returning single value can you help me to get the desire output ?